# List all employees and the number of people they supervise in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, right-join

I have a table of employees. Each employee has an employee id. Some employees have a supervisor field that links back to another employee's id. There are 10 employees, two of which are supervisors, each supervising 4 people. I am trying to get a list of all the employees and the number of other employees they supervise. So far I can only seem to get the supervisors and the number they supervise to show. This is my query:

```
SELECT s.employee_name, COUNT(*)
FROM employee e
     join employee s on e.supervisor_id= s.employee_id
group by s.
order by s.employee_name;
```

I tried changing `JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN` and it will now show me all 10 employees with the two supervisors shown as having 4 people they supervise but it shows all the others having no one to supervise as having 1 instead of 0. I'm sure it's something simple I am missing.

Sample Data:

```
employee_name, employee_name, supervisor_id,
'10111', 'Sydnee K. Stevens' NULL
'10870', 'Colton C. Rocha', '10111'
'11425', 'Astra V. Sharp','10111'
'12973', 'Melanie X. Rojas','10111'
'14451', 'Bethany Roman','10111'
'14597', 'Lydia Edwards', NULL
'16153', 'Selma Q. Conley', '14597'
'17730', 'Kristen B. Malone', '14597'
'17762', 'Barrett B. Bauer', '14597'
'18628', 'Shana Z. Flowers','14597'
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results, please. PS - 'some' have supervisor field?

Comment: Should be "Some employees have a supervisor_id"

Comment: "all the others having no one to supervise as having 1 instead of 0" - This is because of `COUNT(*)`. Try `COUNT(e.supervisor_id)`

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `LEFT` or `RIGHT JOIN` `COUNT(*)` will always be at least `1`. If using `LEFT JOIN` (`RIGHT JOIN` is confusing) you just need to count values from a right table column. `COUNT(column)` will ignore all rows with NULL in that column.

```
SELECT s.*, COUNT(e.supervisor_id) as num_supervised
FROM employee s
LEFT JOIN employee e on e.supervisor_id = s.employee_id
group by s.employee_id
order by s.employee_name;
```

Comment: Could you explain a little why a `left` or `right` with `count(*)` is always at least one? Just so I have a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: @user2328273 `COUNT(*)` will count all rows that have at least one column with a NOT NULL value. While `COUNT(columnName)` only counts rows with NOT NULL values in that column. Look at the example [here](http://rextester.com/JYPH60307) - There is no row containing only NULLs.

Comment: @user2328273 Also have a look at the first comment [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html)

Answer (score 1):

We join your employee table with a select like we would join it with a real table. The select will consist of all supervisor_ids and the number of occurences in the supervisor_id field (records where supervisor_id is null will be ignored).

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee_name, s.supervising 
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN (SELECT supervisor_id, count(*) as supervising 
           FROM employee
           WHERE supervisor_id is NOT NULL
           GROUP BY supervisor_id) AS s
ON(e.employee_id = s.supervisor_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works as expected. Paul's suggestion also worked within what I already had. Get to have more that one way of thinking about a problem.